# Cannot position the page navigation DIV from ASP.NET listview

Tags: jquery, asp.net, listview

I have this page: http://quotestemple.com/Quotes/Words/Photography/All/Page1

And jquery.isotope plugin to order the white boxes, but the problem is that the page navigation is inside a listview and it also gets moved and I cannot position it on top of the page or bottom.

Any ideea how to move the page navigation div on top or bottom of page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place RadDataPager control outside of RadListView's layout template.